# Restore data from overwritten LVM

Tags: backup, xen, lvm, xenserver, restore

I lost all of my data (8 TB) which I collected over the past few years yesterday because I made some seriuos mistakes during the remounting of my LVM.
I run a XenServer5.6 installation with additional 4 harddisks for data storage. An LVM over those 4 HDDs was used to store all of my data.
Yesterday, I reinstalled XenServer and wanted to mount my old Harddrives and add the LVM. I run

> xe sr-create [...]

for all disks (/dev/sdb .. /dev/sde), but that was totally wrong. This command deletes the old LVM on the disks and created an new, empty lvm on every single disk with no partitions. No i got 4 empty harddrives :(

Is it possible to recover some data from that lost LVM volumes? I have no clue how to do it because i deleted all informations about the old LVM. Is there a way to access the files insed that old lvm directly?

Answer (score 1):

Try `vgcfgrestore`. LVM normally saves backup of all LVM metadata in `/etc/lvm/backup` and older backups go in `/etc/lvm/archive`.

To check what backups you have:

```
vgcfgrestore -l <volumegroupname>
```

A dry run of a backup restore:

```
vgcfgrestore -t <volumegroupname>
```

And actually restore the most recent backup:

```
vgcfgrestore <volumegroupname>
```

To restore a different backup (check the output of the `-l` switch):

```
vgcfgrestore -f /etc/lvm/archive.... <volumegroupname>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When are those backups created? The only command I executed was the "xe sr-create.." command, does this create such an backup?

Comment: A backup is created every time you run a command to modify the LVM. So a backup would have been created every time you modify your `lvm` configuration with `lvcreate`, `lvremove`, etc. Or even `vgs`.

Comment: Oh no, there was no backup :( Just one for the XenServer installation lvm... damn! I'll try to read raw data somehow next...

Comment: You can search for file system superblocks using certain tools.  For example, when recovering from a lost disklabel in a BSD system, you can run scan_ffs(8) to discover data about file systems on a given disk.  There should be similar tools for Linux and instructions for recovering the data.